# How to use Threading timers in a while loop

Tags: python, multithreading

### What I need help with.

The only reason I used 2 seconds was to delay the messages but I am using a `while loop:` now since the `for loop:` did not really work the timer delay does not seem to be working for some reason regardless of what I do. I don't want to use `time.sleep()` since it would delay the loops in the future I plan to add multiple threads. It seems easy I think the `threading module` is very bug or at least it does not work the way a person might expect from it but if anyone is experienced with this module it would be a big help. I am sure the answer is simple but I am an idiot that is why I can not figure it out.

```
from threading import Timer


isint = True
while (isint):
    x =input("How many 'somethings' : ")
    try:
        x =int(x)
        isint=False
    except ValueError:
        print("Type in a number.")

def something():
    global x
    if x > 0:
        print('Something')
        x = x-1
    else:
        pass


while True:
    Timer(10 , something).start()
```

Comment: You might wanna have a look at [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

Comment: maybe you should use different value `Timer(10, ...)` `Timer(12, ...)` `Timer(14, ...)` and it will start with different moments

Comment: It seems like it only works with servers.

Comment: I still don't understand what is real problem. Stop writing long sentences about bugs, experiences, etc. but write exactly what you expect and what you get.

Comment: btw; text `did not really work` is totally useless. If something doesn't work then describe it. We can't read in your mind. And code may work different on our computers so we may not see what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use different value for every `Timer`

```
Timer(10, ...) 
Timer(12, ...) 
Timer(14, ...)
```

And with loop

```
for i in range(x):
    Timer(10 + i*2, something).start()
```

and every timer will start 2 seconds later after previous timer without using `sleep()`

Comment: I tried it and I wanted it to be like after every 10 seconds it will print not when 10 seconds is up it will print then all at one time it was a good idea but it really does not help with what i a trying to do.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. It print first message after 10 seconds, next 2 seconds after first, etc. - similar to code with `sleep()`. If you need something different then you have to better explain it. And if you want 10 delay between messages then first need `10`, second `20`, third `30`, etc.

Comment: or you should run only one `Timer(10, something).start()` at start and inside `something` run next `Timer(10, something).start()`

Comment: the only reason i used 2 seconds was to delay the messages but i am using a while loop now since the for loop did not really work
```from time import sleep
from threading import Timer


isint = True
while (isint):
    x =input("How many 'somethings' : ")
    try:
        x =int(x)
        isint=False
    except ValueError:
        print("Type in a number.")

def something():
    global x
    if x > 0:
        print('Something')
        x = x-1
    else:
        pass


while True:
    Timer(10 , something).start()
```

Comment: better put it in question - it will be more readable and more people will see it (so more peolpe may help you)

Comment: Frankly I don't understand what you really want to do. Do you want to repeate `something` forever? Do you want to do something else at the same time? Then run loop `while True` in separated thread.